# YouTube Video Topics/Categories

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm working with YouTube videos and I noticed the field `topicDetails.topicCategories` ([see in the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#topicDetails.topicCategories[])). It's not clear to me if this field is autogenerated by YouTube or if the user has to fill it. I tried to find some relevant field when editing the video but I didn't find it anywhere. So I guess YouTube fills this field based on tags, keywords etc. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

[google Api Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.insert) Check this site to see for which api you need which parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a definitive answer for your question in the [YouTube documentation for topicCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#topicDetails.topicCategories%5B%5D), but I have some evidences that it is automatically calculated by YouTube.

First I couldn't find a way to set it in the configuration options of the channel I created.

Second, they used to have a (now deprecated) attribute called [Guide Category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories) they explicitly say:

> A guideCategory resource identifies a category that YouTube algorithmically assigns based on a channel's content or other indicators, such as the channel's popularity. The list is similar to video categories, with the difference being that a video's uploader can assign a video category but only YouTube can assign a channel category.

So I believe that this *Topic Category* is automatically calculated by You Tube.